# Bag model and MFT

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force, quark-gluon-plasma, mean-field-theory

Can I think of the MIT Bag model as an application of mean field theory (MFT) in nthe domain of nuclear physics? All the interactions between quarks are mediated via strong interaction, whose exact form is yet not known. So is it correct to think that in MIT Bag model, we replace the interactions amongst quarks via an external field with which all the quarks interact (which is the idea of MFT as per my understanding)?

Kindly point out whether I am thinking in the wrong way.

Comment: I was at MIT while the bag model was being developed and although I did not participate directly in the research,I was privy to many of the associated discussions.  I believe it was motivated by MFT type thinking with an additional confinong mechanism that is usually not present in MFT models.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The model has to satisfy the criterion that quarks are confined within the boundary of hadron. Thanks for the input. :)